yas-expand-snippet and yas-lookup-snippet?
I've two small snippets, where I'm trying to expand one snippet inside another. As the snippet that gets expanded is always the same one, and it's always expanded I've been trying to use yas-expand-snippet and yas-lookup-snippet in a transform on the field...
My first snippet is something like,
# key:       CMakeVersion
# name:      CMakeVersion
# type:      snippet
# --
${1:Major}.${2:Minor}${3:.${4:Patch}${5:.${6:Tweak}}}$0

While the second snippet, that I want to expand the first into is,
# key:       cmake_minimum_required
# name:      cmake_minimum_required
# type:      snippet
# --
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION ${1:Minimum$(yas-expand-snippet (yas-lookup-snippet 'CMakeVersion))}${2:...${3:PolicyMax}}${4: FATAL_ERROR})$0

The transform seems to replace the $1 field with just a t (maybe like this?) and I'm not sure I follow why this is happening? I've tried with and without yas-triggers-in-field in the snippets and my config, but I'm unable to get it to play...
Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a better approach? Or can someone spot my mistake?!?
Thanks,
Andy.
